# Iterate through an IList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I iterate through an IList collection and return only n number of records? I am trying to implement paging using an IList object.

Answer (score 2):

Use the very useful PagedList:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-pagedlistt/

Answer (score 1):

```
(From o As Object In myList).Take(n)
```

Hanselman has a good Paginated List class in his ASP .NET MVC tutorial [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx). You should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (int i in myList.Take(4))
{
            // do some stuff
}
```

It's worth noting that for pagination, you'll also want some sort of offset. To do so, you could do the following as well:

> foreach (int i in
>   myList.Skip(40).Take(20)) { }

In C#.